# Visual Studio 2019/Team Explorer: How can I dismiss a connection to Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

Just for testing purposes I connected to Azure DevOps.

Now I want to revert to the situation I was before I connected to Azure DevOps. But I don't seem to be able to do that. Whenever I launch Visual Studio and open Team Explorer, it wants to authenticate me against Azure DevOps:

[image: Can't remove Azure connection]

How can I fully dismiss a connection to Azure DevOps without being forced to reset my Visual Studio profile or re-install Visual Studio 2019?

---

### EDIT

I don't see an Azure DevOps connection listed in the Connect page. And I don't have a `Team` menu item in the menu bar:

[image: Team Explorer 2]

---

### UPDATE

> The Windows credential about the Azure devops.

Actually, I don't have any corresponding entry in the Windows Credential Manager listed:

[image: No credentials]

This may be due to the fact that I didn't connect a workspace file path to a DevOps project collection. (I pressed `Cancel` when I was asked to link `$` to a local path.)

Yesterday, I was quite desperate. Fortunately I didn't delete the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService` folder but just renamed it.

I had deleted the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache` folder, though.

After I renamed the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService` back to its original location (beforehand deleting what has newly been created in that folder), I could restart Visual Studio 2019 normally again.

And here's the new situation: Now everything works as you originally suggested in your first reply. Now I can randomly create and dismiss connections to the AzureDev server. I now even have a `Team` menu item.

Apparently, over time, Visual Studio 2019 must have stored information in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache` that must have caused it to malfunction. After deleting that cache now, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2019/Team Explorer: How can I dismiss a connection to Azure DevOps?

I could reproduce your situation on my side.

If I go to `Team` in the menu and select '`Disconnect from Server`', then I was allowed to delete the connection:

[image]

After removing all repos connections.

Then, I restart the Visual Studio. However, I encountered the same issue as you, and Visual Studio is still authenticates me against Azure DevOps:

[image]

To resolve this issue, I tried the following septs to solve this issue, please check if it helps you:

- Close all the Visual Studio instance and restart the Visual Studio.
- Click the plug icon in Team Explorer to open the Connect page, remove all the connections(if it exists) and the local Git repositories.
- Remove the related credentials from Credential Manager.
- In Credential Manager remove all the Generic Credentials for the Azure devops account.
- Close all Visual Studio instances, delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`.
- Clear Azure devops caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache`.

Now, reopen our Visual Studio with option **Continue without code** rather than the recent project from Azure devops:

[image]

**Update:**

> Which Credential Manager are you referring to? Git? Windows? Would you
> please elaborate?

[image]

The Windows credential about the Azure devops.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Which Credential Manager are you referring to? Git? Windows? Would you please elaborate? After executing steps 1, 2, 5, 6, Visual Studio now starts with an endless loop, asking me to authenticate over and over again. Then after 6 iterations, Visual Studio 2019 crashes.

Comment: See this animation: ![Cannot dismiss Azure DevOps connection](https://i.imgur.com/mVDxjo8.gif)

Comment: I need your help quite fast now.

Comment: @AxD, Update in the answer, please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the connection, click the plug icon in Team Explorer to open the Connect page.  There, you should see the Azure DevOps connection listed.  Connections can be deleted here via the context menu.

Note that if you are currently connected to that Azure DevOps server, then you'll first need to use the main menu to disconnect ("Team->Disconnect from Server").  Once disconnected, you can delete the connection from the Connect page.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't see an Azure DevOps connection listed in the Connect page, and I don't have a Team menu item in the menu bar. See my edited question above.